# Is there a more concise way to select elements within ancestors elements that contain certain classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm selecting a lot of elements in my code based on whether or not an ancestor element contains classes, and wondered if there was a more concise way to do it.

For instance, to select all `<p>` and `<blockquote>` elements nested inside a `<div>` or `<main>` element, which has the class 'orange', I'm writing.

```
$('main.orange p, div.orange p, div.orange blockquote, main.orange blockquote').css('background-color', 'orange');
```

This accomplishes what I want, but it's a little tedious writing out `div.className element, main.className element` for all the elements I want to select. Is there a way to select all `<p>` elements nested in any ancestor with the class 'orange'?

Comment: You can skip the tag name when you are using class name. `:)` Just use `.className element`. That should do.

Comment: Oh, that is more concise, haha!

Comment: Check out the answer boss... `:)`

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider skipping the tag names in case if you don't have other tags using the same class. Also, using a cartesian way will help you minimise this selector:

```
$(".orange").find("blockquote, p");
```

This is one of the best simplified methods. Or if you are specific about the tags:

```
$("main.orange, div.orange").find("blockquote, p");
```

The above is an exact simplification, while I tend to use more of the first style than the above style, as long as the class names aren't used by other elements and I don't want to select them.

Also, I noticed that you are setting some CSS property on the element. I would kindly ask you to please use jQuery (or JavaScript) only for interaction and use CSS fully for presentation.

Have a class, say `.js-orange` and apply it to all those elements. For them, in the CSS, try adding this:

```css
.orange-applied {background-color: orange;}
```

And then in jQuery, just do:

```
$(".js-orange").addClass("orange-applied");
```

This way, you will be able to either `toggleClass` or `removeClass` programmatically and one of the best approaches.

Comment: Also, `$("main, div").filter(".orange").find("blockquote, p")` iirc

Comment: Thank you!  Setting a css value was just an just a quick example I could use, instead of pasting a giant chunk of code into the question here.  I appreciate you going through best practices though.  Good ideas!